# Is there a better way to compute the top of the hour code for repeat interval notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, alarm, hardcode

I have hard coded this Hour to help me fire the local notification at the top of each hour, but something is wrong. Though, I dunno if it's the way I'm testing it, my Xcode behaviour, or the code itself. Anyway, here is the code I made, have a look at it and please guide me to an easier or a better way to code such things. Thank You.

```
NSCalendar *calendar1 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar1 components:(NSHourCalendarUnit |NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
hour = [components hour];
min =[components minute];
sec =[components second];
NSLog(@"hour is %i",hour);

NSLog(@"min is %i",min);

NSLog(@"sec is %i",sec);
if (hour < 24) {
 hour=hour+1;
 } else {
     hour=0;
```

And then..

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] ;
NSDateComponents *componentsForReferenceDate = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[componentsForReferenceDate setHour:hour];
[componentsForReferenceDate setMinute:0];
[componentsForReferenceDate setSecond:0];

 NSDate *fireDateOfNotification = [calendar dateFromComponents: componentsForReferenceDate];

// Create the notification
```

Comment: You never said what was actually going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things to take on board here:

- When asking for the date you don't need to ask for minutes and seconds as you scrap them anyway.
- You should probably set a timeZone
- When the hour is 23 you will add 1, which makes 24 which is not right
- You don't need to create a new `NSDateComponents` object, you can just configure the one you have

  ```
  NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
  calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"];

  NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
  components.hour   = (components.hour + 1) % 24;
  components.minute = 0;
  components.second = 0;

  NSDate *fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
  NSLog(@"%@", fireDate);
  ```

The use of `%` for setting the hour prevents us going over 23

Comment: Is there a difference between timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone]; and timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]; ? and which is better to use?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't showing how you create the notification but the best way to repeat every hour would be to use a `NSHourCalendarUnit` repeat interval.

The local notification object, which is of type `UILocalNotification` has a property named repeatInterval which determines the repeat interval for the delivery of the notification.

```
notification.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;
```

Your notification will repeat every hour, based on the time you specify, so you are setting everything correctly in the `NSDate`, i think just need to set the repeatInterval.